# Loop through all nodes in xml and save path & value of nodes

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have the following xml (see picture) with multiple level of child nodes.
I want to get value and full path of each node.
I have tried to iterate through all the nodes but the grand child nodes are not comping in the loop. If I run a loop within loop then I get all the nodes but I don't feel it is the right way since some of child nodes too have grand children nodes and for those I will have to write another loop.
Is there a easier way to get path and values of all nodes from an xml in c#?

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(Server.MapPath(@"~/XmlFiles/test_uwe.xml"));

XmlNodeList elemList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Page1");

foreach (XmlNode node in elemList) 
{
   //Loop goes here but doesn't catches grand child.
}
```

[image: Xml with multi level child nodes]

Comment: Please post an example of the XML source, not a screen shot, and the output you expect.

Comment: Do you really mean you want to loop through all nodes (attribute nodes, namespace nodes, text nodes, comment nodes ...) or just loop through all elements?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean with grand child nodes: are those the child nodes in the document element?

I think what you are trying todo is iterate through all XmlNodes and log and for each XmlNode also check for it's ChildNodes and do the same for each ChildNode:

```
ProcessNodes(doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes);

private void ProcessNodes(XmlNodeList xmlNodes) {
    foreach (XmlNode xmlNode in xmlNodes) {
        //TODO: Do something here with xmlNode, like logging Name and value

        //Now call ProcessNodes for it's ChildNodes
        ProcessNodes(xmlNode.ChildNodes);
    }
}
```

If you also want to log the DocumentElement you can also change the inputParameter to an XmlNode. The concept of iteration stays the same:

```
ProcessNode(doc.DocumentElement);

private void ProcessNode(XmlNode xmlNode) {
    //TODO: Do something here with xmlNode, like logging Name and value

    foreach (XmlNode childNode in xmlNode.ChildNodes) {
        //Now call ProcessNode for it's Child
        ProcessNode(childNode);
    }
}
```

Comment: @decker Hi, by grand child I mean a node which had a parent node and this parent node is also a child of another parent node.

Comment: Try my suggested method: that will iterate through all nodes and skip none, without you having to hardcode expected node-names.

Comment: @decker I am trying your method, seems like it will solve the problem, will mark your's as answer once I get it right. Thanks a lot m8.

Comment: @Max Also added an alternative in case you also want to log the DocumentElement (in your case Formular1).

Comment: @decker Thanks a lot, your examples were right to the point & solved my problem. Much appreciated.